# How I can go on my back office when i have a fatal error in class-wp.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error, elementor

I have a problem with my website, I can't go on the back office. This is the error message I get when I try to go to the back office:

[image: Screenshot of a PHP fatal error]

Can someone help me please?

I tried to deactivate some plugins, deleted the error line, searched on web a solution, reinstalled a old save of the site. Nothing is working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restore a backup. If you have a backup of your WordPress site, you can try restoring it to a previous version before the error occurred.